# How do I deploy 2 projects in 1 solution?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I’ve created a solution using Visual Web Developer 2012 Express.  The solution has two projects. I use the one-click method to publish the site and although the second project is referenced it didn’t get publish.  I found samples on using macros to publish but only for Winows project and not with MVWD 2012 Express.  Does anyone know of a good tutorial that I may use?

Comment: What type of project is the second project? Are they both web projects?

Comment: If you have two websites within one solution you need to publish them both seperately. If you need classes from one website just create another assembly project and place your common code there.